# Dynamically change border of gbutton in R

Tags: r, gwidgets

I'm using the gWidgets package in R (specifically the RGtk2 toolkit).  I've created some gbuttons and you can specify on creation border=FALSE or border=TRUE.  Is there a way to dynamically change this option?  I know you can change the text on a button using svalue but I can't find a way to change this

```
win <- gwindow()
gg <- ggroup(cont = win)
gb1 <- gbutton("TRUE", border = TRUE, cont = gg)
gb2 <- gbutton("FALSE", border = FALSE, cont = gg)
```

Is there a way to dynamically make gb2 look like gb1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by manipulating the underlying RGtk object, for example:

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
library(RGtk2) ## needed to call underlying methods through $
b <- gbutton("some button", cont=gwindow())

getToolkitWidget(b)$setRelief("none") ## one of GtkReliefStyle values
```

I took the border argument out of gWidgets2, as I didn't know it was useful.